# How do Price Fister Shower faucet works internally (the ones that use the 974-291 cartridge and 971-250 stem)?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I opened up my shower valve and tried to repair it.

I was marveling at the mechanism -- especially because I could not make head or tail on how it would work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a thermostatic valve or a pressure balancing valve?

Comment: I believe it is a pressure balancing valve